# ArcGIS JS - How to destroy, clear, erase, free and get rid of features?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, angular

I'm using ArcGIS JS 4.25.5 and Angular 14.

I have a map where I can dynamically load and unload layers, and this map serves multiple purposes throughout the software, so I have to strip out all the features, destroy them when I navigate to different pages / areas.

How do you properly destroy layers / features?

Currently, I'm doing:

```
removeAllFeatureData(): Promise<void | Error> {
  return new Promise((r) => {
    const layersToDestroy =
      this._view?.map?.layers?.filter(l => l.type === 'feature').length;

    console.log('Layers to Destroy');
    console.log(layersToDestroy);

    if (layersToDestroy) {
      let layersDestroyed = 0;
      this._view.map.layers.forEach((layer) => {
      
      if (layer.type === "feature") {
        console.log('Feature Layer Count + 1');
        layer.clear()
        layer.destroy()
        if (++layersDestroyed === layersToDestroy) {
          this._map.removeAll();
          r(null);
        }
      }
    })
  } else {
    r(null);
  }
})
}
```

But as I move around the software, occasionally I'll see an old layer on the map, which should have been "destroyed" on navigation.  Inside my `ngOnDestroy` I call `removeAllFeatureData` and wait for it to return:

```
try {
  this._clickEvent.remove();
  this._BasemapGalleryWatcher.remove();
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}

this.removeAllFeatureData().then(() => {
  try {
    this._view.ui.empty();
    this._view.popup = null;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  try {
    this._map.removeAll();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  try {
    this._widgets.forEach((widget) => {
      if (widget) {
        try {
          widget.destroy();
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      }
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Is there away to assure all features are destroyed?

If I don't destroy them, my memory gets locked up, and eventually I'll have GB's in use, which is why it's important. I'm using a Store to assure I only allocate a single map, and refuse it throughout the software.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the `view` between pages? The Views have a `destroy()` method you can use, and you can dereference bits like the popup and map, so they don't get destroyed if you want to keep them.
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#destroy

It looks like you are destroying the layers, but do you want to keep the map if it's empty? The map and the layers have their own `destroy()` methods too you can use. It might be simpler to destroy everything and if you need it, you can keep a reference to the maps scale and center as lat/lon you can use to recreate the map and view when you need it.

Comment: The view / map destroy functions don't actually free, release or destroy the memory or free any reference that's held on maps.  I'm completely confused what the destroy functions are actually for, at least regarding the view / map.  

The layer do have a "destroy" function, and that does seem to be somewhat effective, they also have a clear function, which again is somewhat effective, but overall there doesn't seem to exist a way to free all held memory and resources. I've been asking ESRI how you go about this for many versions, starting back in 4.12 or 4.14.